# How to split the csv file based on some condition and write to new file?

Tags: perl, awk

I hv a file like below, i need to get the Value of title(which occurs multiple times in file] and store it in separate file

```
{"card":{"cardName":"43SCX4","portSignalRates":["43SCX4-L-OTU3","43SCX4-C-TENGIGE","43SCX4-C-OTU2","43SCX4-C-FC8G","43SCX4-C-STM64","43SCX4-C-OC192"],"listOfPort":{"43SCX4-L-OTU3":{"portAid":"43SCX4-L-OTU3","signalType":"OTU3","tabNames":["PortDetails","OTU3e2Details"],"title":"OperationalMode",{"label":"Regen","value":"regen"}],"label":"Regen","value":"regen","checked":"","enabled":"true","selected":""},{"type":"dijit.form.Select","name":"Frequency","title":"Transmit Frequency "}}}}
```

I tried with "awk -F, '{}' sample", i'm able to split,but not able to iterate and put it to another file only "title":"********"

Comment: It is not a csv- file. It is json. Look after a json-parser for perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through grep with -oE option.

```
$ grep -oE '\"title\":\"[^"]*"' file
"title":"OperationalMode"
"title":"Transmit Frequency "
```

If you want to get the value of Title then use a lookbehind,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*' file
OperationalMode
Transmit Frequency
```

If you want to save it another file then redirect the output to another file using output redirection `>` operator. Example `grep -oP '(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*' file > outfile`

Comment: i used grep -oP '(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*' file
o/p:OperationalMode
grep -oP '(?<=\"Name\":\")[^"]*' file
o/p:Mode transmit
How to combine the result of both to get o/p as,
OperationalMode:"Mode transmit",

Comment: @user3271040 just use an OR operator. `grep -oP '(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*|(?<=\"Name\":\")[^"]* file`

Comment: o/p's as filename:name

Comment: unclear, if you have any queries please ask it as another question.

Comment: ex:10XANY10G_1.json:Max Frequency in GHz

10XANY10G_1.json:up

10XANY10G_1.json:UP

10XANY10G_1.json:down

Comment: expected was:
up:"UP",

Comment: you get a quick and immediate answer if you post it as question. And also through comments, it's so hard to predict what your wants. That's why i said.